# Maps API v3 clustering at different zoom levels

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer, markermanager

I am working on a map project where I need clustering. I implemented a store locator and used MarkerClusterer which works fine. Now I have another requirement from the customer and I wonder which solution I should use to achieve these goals:

- Zoom level 0: Cluster markers within 1500km distance to each other
- Zoom level 1: Cluster within 1000km
- Zoom level 2: Cluster within 750km
- Zoom level 3: Cluster within 400km
- Zoom level 4 and above: no clustering

I was thinking I should be using MarkerManager and MarkerClusterer together, but I am not sure about that. Any help to get me on the right path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only use `MarkerClusterer`, but you have to modify some options.

To prevent the clusterer acts after level 4, you have to use `maxZoom` property. It defines the max level where the clusterer can cluster marker, so in your case, you have to fix it at 4.

Then, to change the size of the grid depending the zoom level, use `gridSize` property. You can find a definition of all option fields [on the doc.](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html)

So, your MarkerClusterer instanciation will look like something like this :

```
var mcOptions = {gridSize: /*Your value*/, maxZoom: 4};
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, /*your array of markers*/ mcOptions);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I understand the `maxZoom` property. But what would be the process to tell the clusterer to change the `gridSize` based on the zoom level? Should I re-create the cluster each time the zoom level changes? Or can I use `setGridSize` method? If yes, will this be dynamically updated?

Comment: Also, I need to cluster markers based on distance in kilometers and set the grid size in pixel. So I guess I have to make the conversion by myself?

Comment: I never did it personnaly, so I'm not sure of the answer. However, the `setGridSize` method seems to do exactly what you want, so I strongly suggest you to test it. But I'm not sure about clusterer's auto-refresh. And you're right, you'll have to do the conversion pixel / kms by yourself.

Comment: Perfect! That worked like a charm. I added a listener on `zoom_changed` and called `setGridSize` accordingly with the values I calculated. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexB I can not seem to get my head wrap around the gridSize. Can you please explain it a bit please??