# Is it possible to change the grid size in google maps V2?

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

Is it possible to change the grid size of markers in google maps. I have customize the DefaultClusterRenderer to change the colors of the markers, Now I want to change the grid size. I dont know how to do it. I have found the following function in the DefaultClusterRenderer class:

```
private static Point findClosestCluster(List<Point> markers, Point point) {
    if(markers != null && !markers.isEmpty()) {
        double minDistSquared = 10000.0D;
        Point closest = null;
        Iterator i$ = markers.iterator();

        while(i$.hasNext()) {
            Point candidate = (Point)i$.next();
            double dist = distanceSquared(candidate, point);
            if(dist < minDistSquared) {
                closest = candidate;
                minDistSquared = dist;
            }
        }

        return closest;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think if somehow I can change the value of minDistSquared then the grid size of the marker will be change. Please help me how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your grid size depends on the zoom level. You can set this if you're using MarkerClusterer v3. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23341368/4241842). Make sure you also check out the `gridSize` property in the [docs](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) as well.

Comment: @not_a_bot I am using maps v2. V3 only supports javascripts. I have one question that is it legal to edit the classes of google maps library. My problem was solved by editing the function of this NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm class.

Comment: If it works for you, that's great. Although my general policy is if you have to ask whether it's ok, you probably shouldn't do it.